# Printing the names of all the people greater than age 18?

Tags: database, algorithm, language-agnostic, bigdata

This was a pretty good question that was posed to me recently. Suppose we have a hypothetical (insert your favorite data storage tool here) database that consists of the names, ages and address of all the people residing on this planet. Your task is to print out the names of all the people whose age is greater than 18 within an HTML table. How would you go about doing that? Lets say that hypothetically the population is growing at the rate of 1200/per second and the database is updated accordingly(don't ask how). What would be your strategy to print the names of all these people and their addresses on an HTML table?

Comment: Since that's my only task, I'd only insert only the names of people who are over 18 into my database in the first place ;)

Comment: How much would you let your database grow by? Do you have enough space to hold all the >= 18 yr olds in your repository?

Comment: Are you giving the growth rate because you need the solution to display faster than the growth rate? Or is the display supposed to change dynamically?

Comment: @MJB - The growth rate is supposed to indicate the dynamic nature of the underlying data and the expectation is that the display needs to change with time but since you cannot expect either the population growth rate to stay static or the newly born to turn into an 18 year old within the next couple of minutes, the display strategy would need to account for the some future variation of this dataset.

Comment: If you're an experienced database designer, the first thing you'll do is question the requirements. HTML? Really? No . . .

Comment: @Catcall - What are the alternatives to HTML?

Comment: Most of the posts here focus on aggregating the source, what if I want to deal with streaming data?

Comment: @sc_ray: only deaths are really of interest - births would show up in your query results after 18 years...

Comment: @sc_ray: HTML is for helping people read data in a browser. Nobody is ever going to read 7 billion rows in a browser. I'd ask, "What's the real problem?" And I'd be prepared to look stupid by asking that same question more than once. (See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem )

Comment: @Catcall - The intention was not to make you fall into the xy-problem trap but have you emphasize how a naive implementation of writing to plain Html can be turned into something a tad more sophisticated and user-friendly. Pagination/Ajax/Filtered Views..etc..etc

Comment: @sc_ray: And why would you want us to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Storing the *ages* in a DB tables sounds like a recipe for trouble to me - it would be impossible to maintain. You would be better off storing the *birth dates*, then building an index on that column/attribute.
2. You have to get an initial dump of the table for display. Just calculate the date 18 years ago (let's say `D0`) and use a query for any person born earlier than that.
3. Use DB triggers to receive notifications about deaths, so that you can remove them from the table immediately.
4. Since people only get older (unfortunately?), you can use ranged queries to get new additions (i.e. people that become 18 years old since yo last queried the table). E.g. if you want to update the display the next day, you issue a query for the people that were born in day `D0 + 1` only - no need to request the whole table again.
5. You could even *prefetch* the people who reach 18 years of age the next day, keep the entries in memory, and add them to the display at the exact moment they reach that age.

BTW, even with 2KB of data for each person, you get a 18TB database (assuming 50% overhead). Any slightly beefed up server should be able to handle this kind of DB size. On the other hand, the thought of a 12 TB *HTML* table terrifies me...

Oh, and beware of timezone and DST issues - time is such a relative thing these days...

Comment: 2kb is a fair bit of data about each person. You could store all the data on my driver's license in a fraction of that.

Comment: @Nick Johnson: 2kb is a bit pessimistic, but not all that much: 1. non-Latin UTF-8 characters need up to 4 bytes each. 2. To avoid ambiguity, you'd also need the names of the parents. 3. In many countries names are significantly longer than in English-speaking countries. 4. Ditto for city/area names. 5. In a global scale, addresses would need to specify everything: country/area/city/neighbourhood and one to three street names - and you'd probably be surprised how long street names can be in some areas.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see what the problem is.  You don't have to worry about new records being added at all, since none of them will be included in your query unless that query takes 18 or more years to run.  If you have an index on age, and presumably any DB technology sufficient to handle that much data and 1200 inserts a second updates indexes on insert, it should just work.

In the real world, using existing technologies or something like it, I would create a daily snapshot once a day and do queries on that read-only snapshot that would not include records for that day.  That table would certainly be good enough for this query, and most others.

Comment: Why was this downvoted?  It's common courtesy to add a comment when you downvote someone explaining why.

Answer (score 0):

Are you *forced* to aggregate all of the entries into one table?

It would be simpler if you were to create a table for each age group (only around 120 tables would be needed) and just insert the inputs into those, as it's computationally simpler to look over 120 tables when you insert an entry than to look over 6,000,000,000 when looking for entries.